# header and details table query

Tags: sql

I have one master table from that I get encounter ids and a text and I have a detail table, matching fields are encounter id and text. from details table, I need to fetch the latest record as per the date and time and display.

I don't know how to do it. I'm thinking that top 1 should work.

```
select top 1 om.txt_order_enc_id, txt_act_text_display, txt_actionDate, txt_action from order_management_data_ om
inner join order_ o on om.txt_order_enc_id = o.encounterID
                    and om.txt_act_text_display = o.actTextDisplay
where o.actstatus = 'ordered'
and o.actclass = 'REFR'
and o.encounterdate < '20180610'
order by o.encounterdate desc
```

expected result.
latest record encounter id, text, status from detail table.

Comment: Why not try it and see? Post you code if it doesn't work. Those queries don't bite.

Comment: i edited, i want to get latest record from order management table, this is detail table, which will have multiple records, i want to get latest one, order table is master table.

Comment: Did you query work? What was the result of the query you posted?

Comment: no it did not work, because, it just gives me one record. as i used top 1. actually , from header table, i get encounter id, i goto details table and i have multiple records , so out of those need to get data with latest date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First create a `group by` on basis of `encounterID`. Create `row index` for same. And filter out the top 1 record of each group.

```
    ; with cte as (
    select row_number () (partition by o.encounterID order by o.encounterdate desc) as Slno,
    om.txt_order_enc_id, txt_act_text_display, txt_actionDate, txt_action from order_management_data_ om
    inner join order_ o on om.txt_order_enc_id = o.encounterID
                        and om.txt_act_text_display = o.actTextDisplay
    where o.actstatus = 'ordered'
    and o.actclass = 'REFR'
    and o.encounterdate < '20180610'
    )
    select * from cte where Slno = 1
```